# Parallel Big data process

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, parallel-processing

I'm implementing a monitoring system using GPS vehicle and my BIG PROBLEMNB is this, I have 100k data (GPS data) per second parallel to process.

Data is sent from many GPS information (GPSID, latitude, longitude, time), 100k data, with the same format for the second, this information should I process it (process it in some way (?)) To show the route of each gps in a visual system.

My big question is:

As I can "take" this large amount of data being sent every second? and after that process them in the most efficient way to display travel information for each GPS-id

Perhaps the process of grouping? for each GPS-id? I have not really clear things, any additional ideas or functionality will be helpful.

I would like to know some ideas of how to process this much information that applications use?, Algorithms? divided into several computers (how?)? ...

the most likely solution, involving architecture and algorithm, im working with java.

I've been reading about hadoop and map/reduce and i don not know if I could serve.

I just found it: https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm

any idea is appreciated

Info ad: GPS information is created by a script, I must see what the best way to receive such information and probably if I can skip a block of information, since 1 second of lost data blocks of coordinates think not affect the display and gives me more time to process the data, are possibilities, obviously the less information lost is much better

Comment: This is too few information. How are the different data related together, what do you call "process", what you need to do with them...

Comment: Just to echo what @coffee_machine has said: there's way too little information to give meaningful advice.

Comment: @Jesus L. describe your flow a bit, maybe someone will give you more useful advice.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the interest and help, i just tried to explain the question, please any question, do it, i really need help :(

Comment: How are you getting the information and is it necessary to process each block of data or can you skip blocks if the treatment is too slow?

Comment: @tom, GPS information is created by a script, I must see what the best way to receive such information and probably if I can skip a block of information, since 1 second of lost data blocks of coordinates think not affect the display and gives me more time to process the data, are possibilities, obviously the less information lost is much better

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to keep accepting data from the client and creating requests to asynchronously process the data. If when processing starts you know the result will take too long, the item is skipped and the next item is processed. You can consider using a concurrent queue (not shown in example code below) to ensure items are processed in the order they are submitted to the executor service.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ExecutorService executorService = ...

        final long computationTime = 800; // say it tasks 800ms to process the data
        while (someCondition) {
           // receive gpsData from client
           executorService.submit(new ProcessingTask(computationTime, gpsData));
        }
    }

public class ProcessingTask implements Runnable {

    // want response inside a second
    private final long responseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000;
    private final long expectedComputationTime;
    private final Object gpsData;

    public ProcessingTask(long expectedComputationTime, Object gpsData) {
        this.expectedComputationTime = expectedComputationTime;
        this.gpsData = gpsData;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {

        final long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (currentTime > responseTime + expectedComputationTime) {
            // the result will be available too late, skip processing this item
            return;
        }
        // TODO process gpsData
        // TODO send response to client
    }

}
```